# How to copy data and formatting from google sheet a to existing sheet b using google scripts without adding timestamp to dates

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

When using .getValues and .setValues to copy values from sheet A to sheet B, all values copy but date values in sheet A have no timestamp but a timestamp is added to date values in sheet b

Aside from below code, I have tried or researched:

```
sheet.copyTo(destination);// only to create new sheet
setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy');//removes timestamp but sets todays date
sonosFcstDestDateCells.setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');//did not remove date timestamp
```

Here is current code:

```
 function cloneGoogleSheet(ssA, ssB) {
 // source docs
 var sssFcst = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('url');
 // target/destination spreadsheet
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('url');
 //set var for ssA and ssB source and destination
 var ssAFcstSource = sssFcst.getSheetByName("ssA"); //
 var ssAFcstSourceRange = ssAFcstSource.getDataRange(); //
 var ssAFcstSourceA1Range = ssAFcstSourceRange.getA1Notation(); //
 var ssAFcstSourceData = ssAFcstSourceRange.getValues(); //
 var ssBFcstDest = tss.getSheetByName("ssB"); //
 var ssBFcstDestDateCells = ssBFcstDest.getRange("5:5");
 var ssAFcstSourceDateCells = ssAFcstSource.getRange("5:5");
 var sNF = ssAFcstSource.getDataRange().getNumberFormats();
 // Clear the destination sheet before paste
 ssBFcstDest.clear({contentsOnly: true});
 // set the target range to the values of the source data
 ssBFcstDest.getRange(ssAFcstSourceA1Range).setValues(ssAFcstSourceData);
 //this duplicates all formats from ssA to ssB, but does not remove added date 
 //timestamp
 ssBFcstDest.getRange(1,1,ssAFcstSourceData.length,ssAFcstSourceData[0].length).setValues(ssAFcstSourceData).setNumberFormats(sNF);
 };
```

Desired result is to have values copy from sheet A to Sheet B without adding timestamp to date values

Comment: Welcome. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, excluding any private or confidential information.

Comment: "all values copy but date values in sheet A have no timestamp but a timestamp is added to date values in sheet b" Would you please edit your question to clarify and provide an example of what you mean by this?

Comment: @Tedinoz How do I share file? To clarify, sheet A has dates with no timestamp, when above code runs it copies values and adds timestamp to date. Sheet A date format 1/1/2018, sheet b date format after code runs 12/31/2017 16:00:00. In detailing this comment I noticed it is also changing date to 1 day earlier.

Comment: Open the spreadsheet, remove/replace private or confidential data. At top right there is a green button labelled "Share". Click the button, a popup will open "Share with others". Click the icon on that popup where it says "Get Shareable Link". The popup changes, and you should see a line "Anyone with the link can view", click on that and change it to "Anyone with the link can edit". Then click "Done". The URL to the spreadsheet is in your memory; now edit your question and paste the link to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Just found out, due to security policy, I am unable to share sheet, even though I removed all but dates. However I did replicate by creating 2 new sheets ssA and ssB, input and formatted date on ssA manually, ran code, copied to ssB and date on ssB has time stamp. Either something google sheets is doing or code. Any suggestions would be apprecaited.

Comment: When you say "time stamp", are you just talking about how the date is formatted? There must be an innocuous version of the/a spreadsheet that you can share. It's up to you, but unless people can _see_ what you are seeing, there is big risk that this question will go unanswered.

Comment: If you can't/won't share your spreadsheet, then would you please edit your question to include an image showing the date/timestamp problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to copy data from the sheet of one spreadsheet to the sheet of another spreadsheet sheet.

In this example, I created a date field and entered two records:
23 March 2019 and 31 December 1985

This is the output using the following methods:

`copyTo()` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

- 23 March 2019
- 31 December 1985

`getValues()/setValues()` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

- 23/03/2019
- 31/12/1985

`getDisplayValues()/setValues()` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

- 23 March 2019
- 31 December 1985

`getValues()/setValues()` - push to array

- 23/03/2019
- 31/12/1985

`Utilities.formatDate(ssAData[i][0], Session.getScriptTimeZone() ,"dd MMMM yyyy")` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format)

- 23 March 2019
- 31 December 1985

Comment: Replacing getValues() with getDisplayValues copied date values without adding timestamp and also maintained all formatting when copying values from source to destination sheet eliminating need for getNumberFormats(). Thanks for all your help!